# How to extract day, month, year, hour and minutes from a large integer

Tags: r, datetime

In my raw data file (4600 records) date, year, hour and minutes are merged together in a large integer, example:

1205981254 (May 12, 1998, at 12:54)

The problem is that records for dates between day 10 and 31 of each month have 10 digits, while there are only 9 digits of dates between day 1 and 9:

905981254 (May 9, 1998, at 12:54)

I created this raw data file many years ago while being a student, and followed no particular format. How can I extract day, month, year, and time of day from these integers? I have read trough all the previous Qs and As without finding a solution of my particular problem.

Comment: What would be the value, in your encoding scheme, for the date Jan, 1st, 2001, 1h07?

Comment: Are all your dates 19xx? or do you cross into 20xx?

Comment: All dates are from 19xx, and Jan 1st, 1999, 1h07 would be 101990107

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert data back to `POSIXct`/`POSIXlt` format :

```
x <- c(1205981254, 905981254)
x1 <- as.POSIXct(sprintf("%010d", x), format = "%d%m%y%H%M", tz = 'UTC')
x1
#[1] "1998-05-12 12:54:00 UTC" "1998-05-09 12:54:00 UTC"
```

You can then extract whichever information you want from this.

```
#Date      
as.integer(format(x1, "%d"))
#[1] 12  9
#Hour
as.integer(format(x1, "%H"))
#[1] 12 12
#Minute
as.integer(format(x1, "%m"))
#[1] 5 5
```

Comment: Try this with the other example given `905981254`.

Comment: Error message: > test.MR$x1 <- as.POSIXct(sprintf("%010d", test.MR$time), format = "%d%m%y%H%M", tz = 'UTC')
Error in sprintf("%010d", test.MR$time) : 
  invalid format '%010d'; use format %f, %e, %g or %a for numeric objects

Comment: @Dag Seems to work with `x` in my answer. Try `str_pad`, `x1 <- as.POSIXct(stringr::str_pad(x, 10, pad = 0), format = "%d%m%y%H%M", tz = 'UTC')`

Comment: It works. How is the synthax for time zone UTC+2? tz = 'UTC+2' won't work.

Comment: You can probably use `Etc/GMT-2`. Run `OlsonNames()` in your console to get list of valid timezones that can be used.

Answer (score 3):

```
dates <- c( 1205981254, 905981254 )
#convert to character
dates <- as.character( dates )
#convert to posix, based on length.. add a 0 as prefix in case of 9 character-length
dplyr::if_else( nchar(dates) == 10, 
                as.POSIXct( dates, format = "%d%m%y%H%M"),
                as.POSIXct( paste0(0,dates), format = "%d%m%y%H%M") )

[1] "1998-05-12 12:54:00 CEST" "1998-05-09 12:54:00 CEST"
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this works for you if the century of the year stays the same.

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attache Paket: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

x <- 905981254
y <- 1205981254


df <- data.frame(records = as.character(rep(c(x, y), 100))) %>% 
  mutate(records = ifelse(nchar(records) == 9, paste("0", records, sep = ""), records)) %>% 
  mutate(records = as.POSIXct(records, format = "%d%m%y%H%M"))
head(df)
#>               records
#> 1 1998-05-09 12:54:00
#> 2 1998-05-12 12:54:00
#> 3 1998-05-09 12:54:00
#> 4 1998-05-12 12:54:00
#> 5 1998-05-09 12:54:00
#> 6 1998-05-12 12:54:00
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
v1 <- '1205981254'
v2 <- '905981254'
#Extract dates first
nv1 <- as.Date(v1,'%d%m%y%H%M')
nv2 <- as.Date(paste0(0,v2),'%d%m%y%H%M')
#Extract hours
nh1 <- paste0(substr(v1,nchar(v1)-3,nchar(v1)-2),':',substr(v1,nchar(v1)-1,nchar(v1)),':00')
nh2 <- paste0(substr(v2,nchar(v2)-3,nchar(v2)-2),':',substr(v2,nchar(v2)-1,nchar(v2)),':00')
#Concatenate
ndate1 <- paste0(nv1,' ',nh1)
ndate2 <- paste0(nv2,' ',nh2)
#Define as dates
as.POSIXlt(ndate1,tz = 'GMT')
as.POSIXlt(ndate2,tz = 'GMT')

[1] "1998-05-12 12:54:00 GMT"
[1] "1998-05-09 12:54:00 GMT"
```

Answer (score 1):

If all your years are `19XX` and not `20XX` you can use

```
dates <- c(1205981254,905981254)
as.POSIXct(sub("(..)(..)(..)(..)$","-\\1-19\\2 \\3:\\4", dates),format="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")

 "1998-05-12 12:54:00 AST" "1998-05-09 12:54:00 AST"
```